# How can i use an AXIOS GET reponse from one component in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, axios

I can't see how to retrieve my answer in my App.tsx, I get an error saying data.map is not a function, can anyone help me?

**App.tsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import {getUsers} from "./networking/UserAPI";

function App() {

    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const users: any = getUsers();
        setData(users)
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
        {
            data.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**networking/UserAPI.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getUsers = async () => {
    await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users`)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
}
```

Comment: `getUsers()` returns a promise, since it's an async function. You're directly taking that result and using it in `setData(users)`. Promises do not have a `.map()` method.

Comment: You didn’t await getUsers()

Comment: stop using `any`. If you really want to do that then there's no point in using Typescript at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your **UserAPI.ts** file like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users`);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
        throw error; // You can choose to throw the error or handle it as needed
    }
};
```

**App.tsx**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { getUsers } from './path-to-your-API-file'; // Replace 'path-to-your-API-file' with the actual path

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const users = await getUsers(); // Call the getUsers function
                setData(users);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
            <ul>
                {data.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```